# Merge a list of matrices into big matrix(summarizing its values)

Tags: r, matrix, sna

my problem at the moment is the following. I have a big list of matrices(about 1600). Actually it's adjencency matrices of cliques with varying size(from 2:2 to 5:5).
here is example of 2 matrices

first

```
            name1      name2      name3
name1          1          1          1 
name2          1          1          1
name3          1          1          1
```

and second

```
           name4       name5      name6      name7
name4          1          1          1          1
name5          1          1          1          1
name6          1          1          1          1
name7          1          1          1          1
```

I need to merge this matrices into a bigger one
and have something like that:

```
           name1    name2     name3     name4     name5     name6    name7
name1          1          1          1       0         0        0        0
name2          1          1          1       0         0        0        0
name3          1          1          1       0         0        0        0
name4          0          0          0       1         1        1        1
name5          0          0          0       1         1        1        1
name6          0          0          0       1         1        1        1
name7          0          0          0       1         1        1        1
```

But this is not all. If there are similar clique(like the first one for the example), or another one containing old names, i want its values to be summarized with the values in the big matrix. And get the matrix of following form:

```
           name1    name2     name3     name4     name5     name6    name7
name1          2          2          2       0         0        0        0
name2          2          2          2       0         0        0        0
name3          2          2          2       0         0        0        0
name4          0          0          0       1         1        1        1
name5          0          0          0       1         1        1        1
name6          0          0          0       1         1        1        1
name7          0          0          0       1         1        1        1
```

I will need these numbers to identify the power of links in my social network.

This problem seems very complicated for me, so i hope i described it clear enough for you :)

Comment: Can one subset of names appear in more than one clique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a `matrix` of 0's  ('mN') with row names and column names from the `union` of row names and column names of the input matrices, with the dimensions from the `length` of the vectors ('rn/cn').  We place all the matrices in a `list` (`lst`), loop through the matrices, change the values of 'mN' that correspond to row/column index of the individual matrices to 1 and `sum` the corresponding `list` elements with `Reduce`.

```
lst <- list(m1, m2)
rn <- Reduce(union, lapply(lst, rownames))
cn <- Reduce(union, lapply(lst, colnames))
mN <- matrix(0, ncol=length(cn), nrow=length(rn), dimnames=list(rn, cn))

Reduce(`+`,lapply(lst, function(x) {mN[rownames(x), colnames(x)] <- 1; mN})) 
#      name1 name2 name3 name4 name5 name6 name7
#name1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
#name2     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
#name3     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
#name4     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
#name5     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
#name6     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
#name7     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
```

If there are matching row/column names for more than one element, this would do the `sum`

```
lst <- list(m1, m2, m1)
```

and repeating the above steps

```
#      name1 name2 name3 name4 name5 name6 name7
#name1     2     2     2     0     0     0     0
#name2     2     2     2     0     0     0     0
#name3     2     2     2     0     0     0     0
#name4     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
#name5     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
#name6     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
#name7     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(3L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(c("name1", "name2", "name3"), c("name1", 
"name2", "name3")))

m2 <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("name4", "name5", 
"name6", "name7"), c("name4", "name5", "name6", "name7")))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that completely solved all problems in my work

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do it:

```
# Toy data
m1 <- matrix(1, 4, 4, dimnames = list(paste0("name", 1:4), paste0("name", 1:4)))
m2 <- matrix(1, 5, 5, dimnames = list(paste0("name", 5:9), paste0("name", 5:9)))

# Create "your list"
mlist <- list(m1, m2, m1)
```

The strategy is to make a matrix with all the nodes/names and then add the cliques to this:

```
# Get all names
nms <- unique(unlist(lapply(mlist, colnames)))

# Create matrix to hold values
ans <- matrix(0, length(nms), length(nms), dimnames = list(nms, nms))

# Fill in values:
for (i in seq_along(mlist)) {
  n <- colnames(mlist[[i]])
  ans[n, n] <- ans[n, n] + mlist[[i]]
}
print(ans)
#      name1 name2 name3 name4 name5 name6 name7 name8 name9
#name1     2     2     2     2     0     0     0     0     0
#name2     2     2     2     2     0     0     0     0     0
#name3     2     2     2     2     0     0     0     0     0
#name4     2     2     2     2     0     0     0     0     0
#name5     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
#name6     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
#name7     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
#name8     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
#name9     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
```

This should also work for overlapping cliques.

**EDIT** The loop can be hidden away by something like:

```
ans <- matrix(0, length(nms), length(nms), dimnames = list(nms, nms))
lapply(mlist, function(m) {n <- rownames(m); ans[n,n] <<- ans[n,n] + m})
print(ans)
# .. as above ...
```

But, probably more R-ideomatic is the following:

```
ans <- matrix(0, length(nms), length(nms), dimnames = list(nms, nms))
tmp <- lapply(mlist, function(m) {ans[rownames(m),colnames(m)] <-  m; ans})
print(Reduce("+", tmp))
# .. as above ...
```

Using `Reduce` in a similar way as @akrun's answer.

Comment: Thank you, your method produces the same matrix as @akrun's one. This fact allows me to feel completely confident about the produced data